# How to find which application receives my shortcut

Tags: macos, mac

I'm trying to find why some of keyboard shortcuts doesn't work on my mac, for example "CMD+\". I believe the shortcut is grabbed by some another app, but how to find which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

In 10.6 at least, in System Preferences there's a Keyboard Shortcuts tab in the Keyboard control panel. If you haven't checked that, you might see if command-\, for instance, is assigned to any action there.